# Using Google datalab: write csv to storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-datalab

I'm trying to use google datalab, but I can't write csv to GCS(Google Cloud Storage) well.

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from io import BytesIO
df = DataFrame({"a":[1,2],"b":1})
print(df)
>>    | a | b
>>  0 | 1 | 1
>>  1 | 2 | 1
```

In stackoverflow, I found this command

```
%storage write --object gs://my-bucket/data/test.csv --variable df
```

But if I use this command, reading data doesn't work well. Because the data is not separated by comma (separated by space). and it includes index.

```
%storage read --object gs://my-bucket/data/test.csv --variable test_file

df2 = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(test_file))
print(df2)
>>    | a b
>>  0 | 0 1 1
>>  1 | 1 2 1
```

I want to write as csv without index.(like `df.to_csv('test_file.csv',index=False)`

How should I do? Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try the following?

```
import pandas as pd
from io import BytesIO
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1,2],"b":1})
df.to_csv('text.csv', index = False)
!gsutil cp 'text.csv' 'gs://path-to-your-bucket/test.csv'
%gcs read --object gs://path-to-your-bucket/test.csv --variable test_file
df2 = pd.read_csv(BytesIO(test_file))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
This worked well.

I can't understand why many articles suggest %storage command.

Comment: Glad to help! `%storage` has been renamed to `%gcs` according to the [datalab to datalab.google migration guide](https://github.com/googledatalab/pydatalab/wiki/%60datalab%60-to-%60google.datalab%60-Migration-Guide)

Comment: @AnthoniosPartheniou `dest_filename = 'gs://path_to_bucket/' + filename_to_save`. I have this piece of code and I need to move this file into the bucket. But it's not saving in the bucket!  what should I do if I have filename and path in the variable?